# LTSpice .MEAS Command: Measuring Mag and Phase Data

Tags: ltspice

I got a real stumper of a LTSpice question for y'all. I'm do an AC analysis to calculate input impedance by setting the input to AC 1V and then adding the trace "1 / I(v1)" (where V1 is the source). 
[image: LTSpice plot of input impedance]
To automate the process, I'm using the following code:

```
.
.
.

.MEAS AC zi_freq1 FIND 1/I(v1) AT=10
.MEAS AC zi_freq2 FIND 1/I(v1) AT=100
.MEAS AC zi_freq3 FIND 1/I(v1) AT=1000
.MEAS AC zi_freq4 FIND 1/I(v1) AT=10000
.MEAS AC zi_freq5 FIND 1/I(v1) AT=100000
.MEAS AC zi_freq6 FIND 1/I(v1) AT=1000000
.MEAS AC zi_freq7 FIND 1/I(v1) AT=10000000

.
.
.
```

The code is giving me magnitude values that line up with what I'm seeing in the plot. However, the phase values don't exceed -180deg even though the plot clearly shows that from approximately 10kHz to 1MHz the phase is greater than -180deg. What am I doing wrong here? The faulty data seems like an anomaly to me but I want to make sure I'm not making any common errors when writing my .meas commands that I'm overlooking.

Here's the circuit btw:
[image]

Comment: So what values **are** you getting for phase? Are any of the phase values correct?

Comment: @ElliotAlderson The values for 100Hz to 1kHz are correct (in the range of -172 to -177deg). However, the phase values for 10kHz to 1MHz is in the range of -170 to 179deg whereas the plot shows that they should be greater than -180deg. It's almost like there's an asymptote at -180deg and the measured phase values don't exceed this level.

Comment: A simple bogus LC+LC filter shows that the phase goes beyond 180deg, both in plot and in `.meas`, so I suspect there must be something in your schematic, or in what your are doing. You are using `1/I(V1)`, but if you haven't rotated the source, that should actually be `-1/I(V1)` for a correct reading. Since I can't see the schematic, I can only throw guesses.

Comment: Hint: Make the source a 1 A current source, and then you can read off the impedance directly as being numerically equal to the voltage across the input port.

Comment: Thanks for your help everyone! The reason I was getting "wrong" phase values was because there's an option to 'unravel branch wrap' for phase (right-click on phase axis). By default this option is selected and what it does is add (or subtract) 360deg to each phase value so that the phase is continuous if it loops back around. For some reason, the .meas commands deselects the unravel option when measuring phase which is why it looks like the phase values were incorrect when they actually are just in a different format then expected. You gotta love LTSpice :)